# C function pointer and typedef

Tags: c, function, callback, typedef

I have been given a code. I need to use the following function but I am having problems calling it.

```
int myFunction(const struct LQuery *pQuery, 
                   f_Callback Callback,
                   const void *pPriv);
```

And I have the following definition

```
typedef void (f_Callback) (int NumOfRecordsFound,
                          void *pPriv,
                          const tL_QueryResult *pData);
```

I understand that `Callback` should be the the pointer to `my_callbackFunction` but I can't seem to understand how to set the parameters to it. As far as I understand `pQuery` is passed to the callback function but `f_Callback` requires 3 parameters.

i.e

```
int main (int Argc, char *pArgv[])
{
    myFunction(what should go here and WHY)
}
```

Comment: what is your doubt ?..how to pass parameters to call back or how to pass call back ?

Comment: 1) That's not a definition, but a declaration. 2) This will not compile. You cannot pass a function as parameter. `Callback` is not a function pointer!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The callback function will be called from the `myFunction`. You have to pass just your callback function as a parameter. Here's an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef void (f_Callback)(int a,
                          int b,
                          int c);

int myFunction(int a, f_Callback* callback)
{
    callback(a, a+1, a+2);
}

void myCallback(int a, int b, int c)
{
    printf("a: %d, b: %d, c: %d\n", a, b, c);
}

int main()
{
    myFunction(5, &myCallback);
    return 0;
}
```

Expected output:

```
$./a.out
a: 5, b: 6, c: 7
```

Answer (score 2):

The typedef is incorrect. It should be

```
typedef void (*f_Callback) (
              int NumOfRecordsFound,
              f_Callback Callback,
              const void *pPriv);
```

which is a proper pointer-to-function - note the star; otherwise it will declare a typedef for a function prototype, which you cannot use as a variable as such, though it will work in a function declaration.

If you have a function like

```
int myFunction(const struct LQuery *pQuery, 
               f_Callback Callback,
               const void *pPriv);
```

And a callback

```
 void my_callback_function(int records_found, 
                           f_Callback callback, 
                           const void *priv)
 {
      ...
 }
```

You can call `myfunction` simply as

```
myFunction(the_query, my_callback_function, the_private_pointer);
```

The lvalue `my_callback_function` will decay into a pointer-to-function, so no `&` character is needed.

Comment: I know the typedef iss usually put as `typedef void (*f_Callback)` but the code provided is as I have copied and it works.. Thanks for the insight on which case it will work.